# Removing certain rows and replacing values based on a condition

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(2)
d <- data.frame(iteration=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,6),
            value=sample(11),
            var3=sample(11))
      iteration value var3
1          1     3     7
2          1     8     4
3          2     6     8
4          2     2     3
5          2     7     9
6          3     9     11
7          4     1     10
8          5     4     1
9          6    10     2
10         6    11     6
11         6     5     5
```

Now,  I want the following: 
1. **IF** there are **more** than one iteration to remove the **last** row AND replace the value of the **last** row with the previous value. 
So in the example above here is the output that I want:

```
d<-data.frame(iteration=c(1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6),
          value=c(8,6,7,9,1,4,10,5))

     iteration value var3
1         1     8     7
2         2     6     8
3         2     7     3
4         3     9     11
5         4     1     10
6         5     4     1
7         6    10     2
8         6     5     6
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, .(value = if(.N>1) c(value[seq_len(.N-2)], value[.N]) else value), iteration]
#   iteration value
#1:         1     8
#2:         2     6
#3:         2     7
#4:         3     9
#5:         4     1
#6:         5     4
#7:         6    10
#8:         6     5
```

#### Update

Based on the update in OP's post, we can first create a new column with the `lead` values in 'value', assign the 'value1' to 'value' only for those meet the conditions in 'i1', then subset the rows

```
setDT(d)[, value1 := shift(value, type = "lead"), iteration]
i1 <- d[, if(.N >1) .I[.N-1], iteration]$V1 
d[i1, value := value1]
d[d[, if(.N > 1) .I[-.N] else .I, iteration]$V1][, value1 := NULL][]
#   iteration value var3
#1:         1     8    7
#2:         2     6    8
#3:         2     7    3
#4:         3     9   11
#5:         4     1   10
#6:         5     4    1
#7:         6    10    2
#8:         6     5    6
```

Comment: thanks! it is working. But how do I keep the other columns if I have more columns and want to keep the values that were there before?

Comment: @YefR  Updated the post.  I didn't see your comment earlier. sorry

Answer (score 2):

This base R solution using the split-apply-combine methodology returns the same values as @akrun's `data.table` version, although the logic appears to be different.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(d, d$iteration),
                      function(i)
                       if(nrow(i) >= 3) i[-(nrow(i)-1),] else tail(i, 1)))
     iteration value
1            1     8
2.3          2     6
2.5          2     7
3            3     9
4            4     1
5            5     4
6.9          6    10
6.11         6     5
```

The idea is to split the data.frame into a list of data.frames along iteration, then for each data.frame, check if there are more than 2 rows, if yes, grab the first and final row, if no, then return only the final row. `do.call` with `rbind` then compiles these observations into a single data.frame.

Note that this will not work in the presence of other variables.

Comment: @Imo. Thanks! But it seems that this solution will not work if there are more than 3 iterations..

Comment: If there are more than 3, what do you want to do? remove a single row (eg, the next to last row), or all middle rows? This is not clear from the example.

Comment: " Imo. You are right. I want always to remove the last one and replace the value of the **one** before last one with the value of the last one.